# sonar configuration for symfony tests directory

Tags: symfony, sonarqube

im looking for a way to configure multiple test directories at once. This is my current configuration

```
sonar.sources=src

sonar.tests=src/Acme/Bundle/DemoBundle/Tests,src/Acme/Bundle/DatabaseBundle/Tests

sonar.phpUnit.configuration=app/phpunit.xml.dist

sonar.php.tests.reportPath=build/logs/junit.xml
sonar.php.coverage.reportPath=build/logs/clover.xml

sonar.libraries=vendor

sonar.language=php
```

The question is, is there a way to define paths for sonar.tests like

```
src/**/Tests
```

Sonar stops with following error:

```
 The folder 'src/**/Tests' does not exist for DemoProject
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is indeed not possible. The best way to achieve what you want to do is to use inclusions and/or exclusions - which accept wildcards.

For instance:

```
sonar.tests=src
sonar.test.inclusions=**/Tests/**
```

You can learn more on ["Narrowing the focus" documentation page](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/narrowing-the-focus.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The only additional question is if there is any difference between tests and exlude property (exept accepting wildcards)